# how to iterate through model to find similar value in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, model

Im trying to implement an Assign IP system, where the Administrator of the MVC web application can assign IP addresses which in effect identify locations/Workstations like the image below

[image]

Now, i want this user-assigned IP to compare to the IP of the machine that opens of the MVC application, so that any data sent from that IP address has the location stated.
I was thinking maybe a method to search through or iterate through and find the matched IP address, i ve tried to implement it below but stuck on how to iterate through and find a match

```
    public static string LocationIPAssign()
    {
        var model = new Location();

        string workstationLocation = ServerIPName();
        foreach (Location location in model.Locations) // ICollection<Location>, IList<Location>
        {
            if (location.AssignedIP == workstationLocation)
            {
                // do whatever you have to do with your locationToAssign
            }
        }
        return workstationLocation;
    }
}
```

Any tips or ideas is appreciated

If you request any further code i would be happy to help

UPDATED
Location Model

```
[Table("Location")]
public partial class Location
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Location()
    {
        Jobs = new HashSet<Job>();
    }

    public int LocationID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Location Name")]
    public string LocationName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid IP Address")]
    public string AssignedIP { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }

}
```

[image]

Comment: what _is_ your model?

Comment: IP of the user on the page, so there will be numerous workstations accessing the MVC app on the intranet, i want the IP address of those workstations so that the MVC app can identify and assign names to the each workstation

Comment: could your post your model?

Comment: @stefankmitph updated with location model

Comment: do you want to loop through `Location` or `ICollection<Jobs>`?

Comment: location @stefankmitph

Comment: so i guess you have a List or Collection or whatever of your `Location` object? (f.e. `List<Location>`)

Comment: yes i created one there now as a collection called "Locations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through your collection/list and find the workstationLocation:

```
public static string LocationIPAssign(Location locationToAssign)  
{ 
    string workstationLocation = ComputerIPName();
    foreach(Location location in Locations) // ICollection<Location>, IList<Location>
    { 
        if(location.AssignedIP == workstationLocation) 
        {
            // do whatever you have to do with your locationToAssign
        }
    }
    return workstationLocation;
}
```

Comment: i tried to implement this but i get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error, locating the error is coming from  the foreach

Comment: @goldeneye which object is null?

Comment: just a guess: is `Locations` in your model null?

Comment: Im a bit confused so sorry for the silly question, but if i write "public  ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }" into the model, should it not make the model class into a collection? if yes then the "Locations" is not null, if no then "Locations" is null...do you understand what i mean by that?

Comment: i understand. are you working with Entity Framework?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76196/discussion-between-stefankmitph-and-goldeneye).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Lambda expression for it.

```
Locations.where( location => location.AssignedIP == workstationLocation );
```